# Docker compose not mounting volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gogs

If I run this command the volume mounts and the container starts as expected with initialized state:

```
docker run --name gogs --net mk1net --ip 203.0.113.3 -v gogs-data:/data -d gogs/gogs
```

However if I run the corresponding `docker-compose` script the volume does not mount.  The container still starts up, but without the state it reads on startup.

```
  version: '3'
  services:
    gogs:
      image: gogs/gogs
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
      volumes: 
        - gogs-data:/data
      networks: 
        mk1net:
          ipv4_address: 203.0.113.3
  volumes:
    gogs-data:
  networks:
    mk1net:
      ipam:
        config:
          - subnet: 203.0.113.0/24
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Works for me both ways. Not sure what your issue is / what you're seeing? What state is it reading? What are you expecting to be where? What isn't what you're expecting it to be?

Comment: The `gogs-data` volume holds the current gogs repository data as well as gogs configuration files.   When I start the container using `docker-compose` gogs starts up as if it has never been configured, but when I start it using the `docker` command the volume mounts and gogs reads the current configuration information from the volume and displays repositories, etc.... Did you create a volume containing configuration data on your try?

Comment: Works absolutely fine. I changed the name of the project, and added a couple users (no repos but I don't see why that would be different if they live in the same dir), they persist a restart using compose. I didn't use your ipam / net configuration, but otherwise just copy / pasted your compose file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your command, the `gogs-data` volume was defined outside the docker compose file, probably using something like:

```
docker volume create gogs-data
```

If so then you need to specify it as external inside your docker compose file like this:

```
  volumes:
    gogs-data:
      external: true
```

You can also define a different name for your external volume and keep using current volume name inside your docker compose file to avoid naming conflicts, like for example, let's say your project is about selling cars so you want the external volume to be call `selling-cars-gogs-data` but want to keep it simple as `gogs-data` inside your docker compose file, then you can do this:

```
  volumes:
    gogs-data:
      external:
        name: selling-cars-gogs-data
```

Or even better using environment variable to set the volume name for a more dynamic docker compose design, like this:

```
  volumes:
    gogs-data:
      external:
        name: "${MY_GOGS_DATA_VOLUME}"
```

And then start your docker compose like this:

```
env MY_GOGS_DATA_VOLUME='selling-cars-gogs-data' docker-compose up
```

Hope this helps, here is also a link to the docker compose external volumes documentation in case you want to learn more: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external

You can make pretty much everything external, including container linking to connect to other docker compose containers.

Comment: Excellent answer - Thank you very much!